# Can I encrypt a file multiple times without an exponential file increase?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

The below results in an exponential increase in size for `encrypted`:

```
let original = 'something'
let passphrase = 'whatever'
let times = 100
let i = 0

let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(original, passphrase).toString()

while (i < times) {
  encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encrypted, passphrase).toString()
  i++
}
```

Is there some other CryptoJS algorithm/method/approach I can use that will *not* result in an exponential size increase?

Or is this not possible?

**NOTE:** If I don't use `toString()` it breaks when I try to re-encrypt what has already been encrypted. I get a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Invalid array length`.

Comment: Yes, don't use `toString()`, the file size increase will be it converting to base64 each iteration and nothing to do with the encryption.

Comment: If I don't it breaks. I get a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Invalid array length` from CryptoJS when I try to re-encrypt the result of the first encryption.

Comment: Tangential, but can you elaborate why you need to re-encrypt data that's already encrypted? Generally, there is minimal benefit to doing this and doing so actually can make your system "more risky" - [relevant Security.SE thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58781/does-using-the-same-encryption-algorithm-multiple-times-make-a-difference).

Comment: I want the result to then be decrypted iteratively.

Comment: you can convert back to a wordarray using `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse`. That should reduce how much it increases each time and you can pass the wordarray to `encrypt`.  The return value is an object with various components.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Could you provide me with some code please? I'm trying `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse` but apparently I'm not using it the right way (or in the right place) so I'm getting errors. :-/ You can make this the answer if you like if it will achieve what I want. I know people are confused as to *why* I want this, but it's irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: Is this what you meant: `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(original, passphrase).toString())` ?

Comment: Actually, your WordArray solution does reduce the size significantly (!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code would timeout for me. The encryption string apparently getting very long as it was base64 encoded.

We can reduce how much it increases by encrypting the wordarray instead of the base64 encoded version of the wordarray:

```
let original = 'something'
let passphrase = 'whatever'
let times = 100
let i = 0

let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(original, passphrase).toString()
encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted)

while (i < times) {
  encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encrypted, passphrase).toString()
  i++
  encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dwvxua96/

This runs fast and creates a string that grows by only a few bytes each iteration.  You can probably reduce that more by setting padding options, or passing in a key/iv pair which may prevent the addition of a salt parameter.

the decryption would look like:

```
i = 0
while (i <= times) {
  encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, passphrase)
  encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted);
  i++
}


encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted);
encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(encrypted)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with the decryption though. Could you include the decryption as well please  in your code ?

Comment: see updated fiddle for details: http://jsfiddle.net/dwvxua96/1/

Comment: This works great! If you only know the `encrypted` & the `passphrase` is it possible to bypass (cheat) all the necessary decryption loops and get to the `original` faster ?